# How to prove the convergence of thsi sequence of integrals?

Tags: calculus, analysis

Suppose $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function.
Then, show that:
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}n\int_{0}^{1}x^nf(x)dx=f(1)$$
I have no idea how to use the continuity of the function in $[0,1]$ for my advantage.I tried observing whether the sequence is increasing or decreasing. But again I have no idea about $f(x)$.

Comment: Likely to be  a duplicate. Make the substitution $y=x^{n}$.

Comment: $n\int_{0}^{1}{x^nf(x)dx}=n\int_{0}^{1}{x^n(f(x)-f(1))dx}+n\int_{0}^{1}{x^nf(1)dx}=n\int_{0}^{1}{x^n(f(x)-f(1))dx}+\frac{n}{n+1}f(1).$ Now use the continuity of $f$ at $1$.